# Does Snowflake execute a "single" single query on multiple nodes or a single node in a Cluster?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When a "single" query is executed on a Snowflake cluster, will it use (if available) as many as the nodes in parallel to execute the query, or just one single node in the cluster?

I am specifically looking for scaling strategy on how to speed up the following query

```
INSERT INTO x SELECT FROM y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, Snowflake will try to run the query in parallel and use all nodes in the cluster, but in rare cases, it may run on only a partition of nodes. For example, if the data source is so small, if there's one file to ingest with COPY command, or you are calling a JavaScript stored procedure for processing data.

Here is a simple demonstration. The following query will run on only 1 node, no matter how many nodes the cluster has:

```
create or replace table dummy_test (id varchar) as 
select randstr(2000, random()) from table(generator(rowcount=>500000));
```

Because the data source is a generator (which can not be read in parallel). You may try to run it on various sized warehouses and you will see that it will complete around 55 seconds (in case there is no other workload in warehouse).

As Simeon and Mike mentioned, a query can be executed in one cluster in multi-cluster warehouses. Multi-cluster warehouses are for increasing concurrency.

Comment: This is a really good example of how "not all things scale" on larger warehouses.

Comment: Gokhan.  I have a query like INSERT INTO x SELECT FROM y. Will this run on multiple node, since the data should supposedly be chunked?

Comment: Yes it should run on multiple nodes unless the table is so small.

Comment: are you sure that JavaScript Stored procs run only on a single node within a cluster even when it is not wrapped in a transaction explicitly? cc: @SimeonPilgrim

Comment: @JohnEipe Yes, I'm sure. But most of the time, a JS SP is just an orchestrator. It calls child JOBs (by using snowflake SP API) and the main work is done by these child jobs. Of course these child jobs will be distributed as any other query. In short, if you run an SP which will call an INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE on a XLarge WH, this SP itself will use only 1 node, but the rest may use all nodes in the WH.

Comment: got it and I believe it makes sense. Now when you think the same about snowpark or python or java procedures, I wonder if that is still true. If I make 2 session calls `session.sql(f'SELECT * FROM {table_name}')`  each of these will get distributed but if I store the result from both in DFs, and work on it, wouldn't both objects and the operations executed on the DFs run on a single node that is executing the proc?

Comment: I do not work with Python, Java or Snowpark SPs. So I might be wrong but as I remember, Snowpark converts your command to internal SQL queries, so I expect that Snowpark procedures will be distributed efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a [multi-cluster warehouse](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-multicluster.html), just a single cluster. But in the context of a multi-node cluster (aka Large or Extra Large warehouse) across all nodes in the cluster.

So large questions are better run on larger sized node, and large volumes of queries run best against clusters of correctly sized nodes (from a average wait time) but of course this costs more.. but if you had a fixed pool of queries, that total cost should be the same running them on a wider cluster, just less wall clock-time.

This is a good read also on the topic of [scaling](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#scaling-up-vs-scaling-out)

Comment: Just a single *cluster*.  The size of the warehouse cluster will determine how many nodes that query executes on.  So, a Small (2 nodes), 2-cluster multi-cluster warehouse, that query will execute on 2 nodes on just 1 of the 2 clusters.  The links above are the right place to read up on it.